# Changing sequence of filenames using bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have files with filenames in a specific sequence order from 0000 to 5933
The first file has '0000' as suffix in the filename

```
j0000.txt
j0001.txt
.
.
j5933.txt
```

I want the sequencial filenames to be like this -

```
j1.txt
j2.txt
.
.
j5934.txt
```

Any suggestions using 'for' loop?

Comment: After renaming they are no longer in the same sequence.

Comment: Of course, the new sequence is no longer as the previous. Suppose, we have files {j0000, j0001,....j5933}. The total count of numbers considering '0000' as an numerical element. Then, there will be 5934 files. If I want to change the sequence to {j1, j2, .....j5934}. The new sequence will not have 'j0000', but rather named as j1.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {0000..5933};do 
   k=$((10#$i+1)) 
   mv j${i}.txt j${k}.txt 
done
```